# New Drush install instructions use Composer for install, even on Drupal 7?

Tags: drush, installation, composer

The current Github install instructions for drush (http://docs.drush.org/en/master/install/#git-clone-ie-manual-install) say as the last step:

> From Drush root, run Composer to fetch dependencies.
>
> $ composer install

Since Drupal 7 does not usually have Composer installed, I assume these are Drupal 8 specific instructions.

Where can I find a link to instructions for installing Drush for a Drupal 7 install, where composer is not present?

Comment: Look at: [Download Composer](https://getcomposer.org/download/) to install Composer. Then take it from there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Drush uses composer to install its dependencies, so please follow the composer instructions regardless of whether you plan to use drush with Drupal 7 or Drupal 8.